# VHDL code error : near text e_my.vhd(61)"my_7segdec"; expecting ";", or "port", or "generic"

Tags: vhdl

I was writing a code for a circuit involving three 7segment displays and a mux with selection inputs to select which character appears on the displays

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity e_my is

port(SW      : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
      LEDR : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
      HEX0, HEX1, HEX2 : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6));
end entity e_my;
 
architecture a_my of e_my is

component e_my_2bit3to1mux is
port(slv_u, slv_S : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      slv_v, slv_w : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      slv_m             : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));

end component;

component e_my_7segdec is 

port(slv_C : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      slv_display: out std_logic_vector(0 to 6));
      
end component;

signal slv_ch_Sel_int : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal slv_ch1_int,slv_ch2_int,slv_ch3_int : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal slv_H2_Ch_int,slv_H1_Ch_int, slv_H0_Ch_int : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin

LEDR <= SW;

slv_ch_Sel_int <= SW(9 downto 8);
slv_ch1_int <= SW(5 downto 4);
slv_ch2_int <= Sw(3 downto 2);
slv_ch3_int <= SW(1 downto 0);

I_M2: e_my_2bit3to1mux port map (slv_S => slv_ch_Sel_int,
                                          slv_u => slv_ch1_int,
                                          slv_v => slv_ch2_int,
                                          slv_w => slv_ch3_int,
                                          slv_m => slv_H2_Ch_int);
                                          
I_M1: e_my_2bit3to1mux port map (slv_S => slv_ch_Sel_int,
                                          slv_u => slv_ch2_int,
                                          slv_v => slv_ch3_int,
                                          slv_w => slv_ch1_int,
                                          slv_m => slv_H1_Ch_int);
                                          
I_M0: e_my_2bit3to1mux port map (slv_S => slv_ch_Sel_int,
                                          slv_u => slv_ch3_int,
                                          slv_v => slv_ch1_int,
                                          slv_w => slv_ch2_int,
                                          slv_m => slv_H0_Ch_int);    
                                          
                                          
I_H2: e_my_7segdec port map (slv_H2_Ch_int, HEX2);

I_H1: e my_7segdec port map (slv_H1_Ch_int, HEX1);

I_H0: e_my_7segdec port map (slv_H0_Ch_int, HEX0);

end architecture a_my;
```

These are the errors.
Both are at the last line labeled I_H1. I dont understand. There is a 'port' near that text, but it still says its expecting.

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at e_my.vhd(61) near text "my_7segdec";  expecting ";", or "port", or "generic"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at e_my.vhd(61) near text ";";  expecting "<="

Comment: you are missing an `_` between `e` and `my_7seg` in the 2nd instantiation

Comment: The first syntax error is caused by a typo. Syntax errors can be hard to generate error messages for, identifiers that aren't reserved words have no meaning yet. Without looking up declarations it's left to the error message reader to notice the identifier `my_7segdec` isn't used in any other place and isn't declared. There is no place in syntax intermediary production current_statement that can start with two successive regular identifiers as tokens without intervening reserved words or delimiters. The second error is from going on, making an invalid assumption as to the cause of the first.